# Why doesn't the chmod command recognize the content of DIR as a directory?

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm trying to write a makefile to do the following when executed:

```
CMVC_VIEW = ../../.. 
TB_DIR = $(CMVC_VIEW)/tarball_images 
SMAC_TOOLS = $(TB_DIR)/smac_tools 
SMAC_BIN = $(SMAC_TOOLS)/bin 
DIR_LIST = $(TB_DIR) \
    $(SMAC_TOOLS) \
    $(SMAC_BIN)

install:
    rm -f *.o
    for DIR in $(DIR_LIST); do \
      echo $${DIR}; \
      chmod 2775 $${DIR}; \
    done
```

When the makefile is run, however, i get an error saying that chmod: missing operand after `2775`.  I don't understand why this is happening, given that `$${DIR}` should contain the path corresponding to the directory that needs its access permissions changed.

This seems to work when I replace `$${DIR}` with a static directory path.

For the purposes of this makefile, suppose that `DIR_LIST` macro is assigned to a list of directories separated by whitespace.

Comment: What does `$(DIR_LIST)` contain?  What does the `echo` statement immediately before the `chmod` statement display?

Comment: It's just a list of directories separated by a space. For example: /tmp/justin1 /tmp/justin2 /tmp/justin3

Comment: That was half my question.  Can you show us the *actual* line that sets `DIR_LIST`?  Was this code cut and pasted verbatim from your Makefile?  This code looks just fine and works as expected when I run it after setting `DIR_LIST` in a sample Makefile.

Comment: `CMVC_VIEW      = ../../..
    TB_DIR         = $(CMVC_VIEW)/tarball_images
    SMAC_TOOLS     = $(TB_DIR)/smac_tools
    SMAC_BIN       = $(SMAC_TOOLS)/bin

    DIR_LIST       = $(TB_DIR) \
       $(SMAC_TOOLS) \
       $(SMAC_BIN) \`

Comment: The echo statement will display each directory followed by a newline character. For some reason, $${DIR} works with echo, but not with chmod 2775.

Comment: Hmm.  Still looks fine (and seems to work fine).  Any chance you can post a link to your actual Makefile (e.g. to gist or pastebin or something)?  I'm wondering if there is some sort of whitespace issue or something going on that's not going to be apparent in these excerpts.

Comment: It would also help if you 1) showed us the actual output of `make`, and 2) tried with a simpler list, e.g. `DIR_LIST := /tmp/justin1`.

Comment: To me, this looks like something unexpected happening in the shell, not in `make` itself. After all, `${DIR}` is not even known by `make`, because it is a variable of the for loop executed by the shell (found in `$SHELL`)

Comment: You could try the following to analyse your problem: `make SHELL="/bin/bash -x"`. That will show you what the shell is actually doing, because it will print debug information.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting confused by make variable references and shell variable references.  Remember, make will interpret any string like `$(FOO)` as a reference to a *make* variable, lookup the variable with that name, and replace the reference with the value.  Your shell-based `for` loop creates a *shell* variable called DIR, but since you have (had) just `$(DIR)`, make was trying (and failing) to find a make variable called DIR.

Your solution works because the double `$` prevents make from doing its own variable reference resolution, so the literal `$(DIR)` gets passed to the shell, which then does its own variable resolution!  That works, of course, because the `for` loop created the DIR variable.